# Binary addition in c, why does run time error occur?

Tags: c, binary

i'm trying to write a code which can convert 2 decimal numbers 0 to 1 into binary, then adding them and printing the binary values for the 2 initial numbers AND the final sum. It compiles with no problems however when I run it crashes right after it converts and prints num1 and num2 (the initial numbers), I can't seem to find the problem. 
the general formula for binary addition is:

*ith bit of sum = ith bit of binary1 + ith bit of binary2 + carry factor (0 or 1)

if sum > 1, subtract 2 and add 1 to the next operation (which is the carry factor i mentions earlier)

Below is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Converting decimal number to a binary number
void convertDecToBin(double num, int len, int binary[]) {

    // this function STORES conversion result in binary[]

    double tmp = num;
    binary[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        tmp *= 2;
        binary[i + 1] = tmp >= 1;
        if (tmp >= 1) {
            tmp -= 1;    
        }
    }

}


// Binary number addition
void addTwoBinary(int binary1[], int binary2[], int sum[]) {

    int tmp;
    int carry;

    for (unsigned int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (i == 20 || tmp <= 1) {
            carry = 0;
        }
        else if (tmp > 1) {
            carry = 1;
        }
        sum[i] = binary1[i] + binary2[i] + carry;
        tmp = sum[i];
        if (sum[i] > 1) {
            sum[i]-=2;
        }
    }
}

//Printing the numbers
void PrintBinary(int binary[], int len) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            printf("%d", binary[i]);

    }
}

int main(void) {

    double num1, num2;
    int binary1[30], binary2[30], sum[30];

    scanf("%lf", &num1);
    scanf("%lf", &num2);

    convertDecToBin(num1, 30, binary1);
    convertDecToBin(num2, 30, binary2);

    printf("num1 is ");
    PrintBinary(binary1, 21);
    printf("\nnum2 is ");
    PrintBinary(binary2, 21);

    addTwoBinary(binary1, binary2, sum);

    printf("\nsum is ");
    PrintBinary(sum, 21);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs)

Comment: `binary[i + 1]` will access `binary[30]` in the last iteration leading to undefined behavior since the valid locations are `0 ... 29`

Comment: `for (unsigned int i = 20; i >= 0; i--) {` those loops are wrong. Since it's `unsigned`, `i >= 0` will never be false, so `i` is just going to roll over to 4.2 billion when decreasing at `0`, causing undefined behavior on the next `sum[i]`.

Comment: @Blaze Thank you! Just had to remove the unsigned and the code works.